# Earth terraformed to a cube, then turned back to a globe?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, terraforming

I vaguely remember reading a short story or novella, probably in the late 1980s or early 1990s, where, across the space of a couple of generations, something odd (affecting gravity maybe?) required that Earth be turned into a cube. Then, once kids had been born knowing only the cube-world, they had to reverse the process (so these kids perceived the horizon as being U-shaped, being accustomed to the edges of the cube).

That's pretty much all I remember. Any ideas?

Comment: This probably isn't it, but Charlie Stross wrote [Missile Gap](http://subterraneanpress.com/index.php/magazine/spring2007/fiction-missile-gap-by-charles-stross/), in which the Earth was flattened out, by its being transferred to a massive disc-world (by unknown aliens). It wasn't turned back, though - but gravity *was* altered, to where missiles encountered increasing g-forces the higher they travelled (and so couldn't escape from the surface).

Comment: @JohnC No, it's not Charlie; it's way older than that. Good book, that, though :o)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This story is "Cubeworld", by Henry H. Gross.  It was published in the anthology [*Mathenauts*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?21699) (1987.)

Comment: That sounds familiar, thank you. I'm not 100% certain until I can find a copy (which I'm not gonna do having just arrived late to work), but I'm gonna preemptively give you the green tick anyway ;o)

Comment: If I remember tomorrow I'll dig out my copy of Mathenauts and re-read it.